# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'super'. [04/Apr/2020 18:15:11] "GET /super_user HTTP/1.1" 500 132224

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

My project is enabling the user to write a post and every post have a category and every category have a supervisor, so I faced a problem I can’t get all posts for the specific category of specific supervisor.

**My models**

```py
class PostCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class UserSupervisorSpecialist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_id", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    category = models.OneToOneField(CategoryPost, related_name="category_id", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    content = RichTextField()
    post_category = models.ManyToManyField(CategoryPost)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False) #0 -> suspend
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0) #0 -> No like yet
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(UserSupervisorSpecialist, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def snippet(self):
        return self.content[:150]
```

**My views:**

```py
def control_spanle(request):
    category = UserSupervisorSpecialist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    post_filter = Post.objects.filter(supervisor=request.user.username)
    return render(request, 'supervisor/controle_panel.html',{'Category':category,'post_filter':post_filter})
```

Comment: It is better to not defining a role with a new model. This may be done with a new attribute on User model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote a queryset on Post model without specifying a field, while comparing it a string.

You may fix this issue by changing this line

```py
post_filter = Post.objects.filter(supervisor=request.user.username)
```

to:

```py
post_filter = Post.objects.filter(supervisor__name=request.user.username)
```